# show error in react native when internet connection isn't good

Tags: react-native

I'am doing the last modification on my react native application.

Well, the problem that I get is that when I enter my informations to connect, I'm showin a small boxDialog to say that the verification of your data is working (this time is for comparing information that user entered and sql server data) so when it's correct I'm accessing to home page.

My problem is sometimes, the internet isn't that good so I need that when verification take longer time to show an error saying "please verify your internet connection"

I don't know if there is a method or specific function!!

```
 constructor(props){
       super(props);
       this.state={
         isModalVisible:false,
}}
 openModal = () =>{
    this.setState({
    isModalVisible:true
    }) }


    userRegister = () =>{
      this.openModal();

   fetch('http://192.168.1.7:80/recup.php',{
   method:'post',
   header:{
   'Accept':'application/json',
   'Content-type' :'application/json'
   },
   body:JSON.stringify({email:usermail,password:password,})})
   .then((responseData)=>responseData.text())
   .then((responseJson)=>{
   if(responseJson =='Data Matched'){
     this.props.navigation.navigate( 'Welcome')}
   else{
     alert("Merci de saisir vos données correctement")}
   })
   .catch((error)=>{console.error(error);})
   }
  
    render() {
if(!this.state.isLoading){
  return(
       ....
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.butt} onPress={this.userRegister}> 
                           <Text>Connection</Text</TouchableOpacity>
      ....
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access this (I mean if you want to fetch) url http://192.168.1.7:80/recup.php you should have proper internet connection.
You can handle this with this react-native-netinfo library. https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-netinfo